# dsolve throwing an error while trying to solve system of ODEs

Tags: ode, mupad, dsolve

```
syms X1(t) X2(t) X3(t) X4(t) X5(t) X6(t) X7(t) X8(t) X9(t) X10(t)
X = [X1; X2; X3; X4; X5; X6; X7; X8; X9; X10];
X0 = X_0;
eqn = diff(X) == -1*A*X;
[X1Sol(t) X2Sol(t) X3Sol(t) X4Sol(t) X5Sol(t) X6Sol(t) X7Sol(t) X8Sol(t) X9Sol(t) X10Sol(t) ] = dsolve(eqn, X0);
```

Where A is some 10x10 Matrix and X_0 is a column vector with 10 elements whose values are calculated beforehand. When I compile this code Matlab throws me the following error:

> Error using mupadengine/feval (line 157) MuPAD error: Error: Invalid
>   equations. [ode::new]
>
> Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve (line 325) T =
>   feval(symengine,'symobj::dsolve',sys,x,options);
>
> Error in dsolve (line 186) sol = mupadDsolve(args, options);

Can anyone tell me what is going on and what is the rectification? I use Matlab R2012a.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to find any error when include `X_0` and `A` in `sysms`

```
syms X1(t) X2(t) X3(t) X4(t) X5(t) X6(t) X7(t) X8(t) X9(t) X10(t) X_0 A
X = [X1; X2; X3; X4; X5; X6; X7; X8; X9; X10];
X0 = X_0;
eqn = diff(X) == -1*A*X;
[X1Sol(t) X2Sol(t) X3Sol(t) X4Sol(t) X5Sol(t) X6Sol(t) X7Sol(t) X8Sol(t) X9Sol(t) X10Sol(t) ] = dsolve(eqn,X0)
```